# Prometheus for Tensorflow Serving

Tags: docker, tensorflow, prometheus, tensorflow-serving

What are the steps to use the Prometheus exporter for Tensorflow serving?
According to 1.11 TF serving supports prometheus metrics:
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/releases/tag/1.11.0

I'm starting a docker from the example https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker and the following:

docker run -p 8501:8501 -p 8500:8500 \
--mount type=bind,\
source=/tmp/tfserving/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu,\
target=/models/half_plus_two \
-e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two -t tensorflow/serving &

Prometheus configuration file:
global:
  scrape_interval:     10s
  evaluation_interval: 10s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'tf-serving-monitor'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'tensorflow'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8501']

But prometheus fails to find the metrics exposed by tf serving.
Is there a specific port I should open on docker or some parameter I should pass to TF serving?

Answer (score 5):

[According to the release notes you linked to](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/commit/021efbd3281aa815cab0b35eab6d6d25249c12d4) TensorFlow exports Prometheus metrics at `/monitoring/prometheus/metrics` (as opposed to Prometheus' default `/metrics`). So at the very least you need to add a `metrics_path` to your config:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'tensorflow'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: '/monitoring/prometheus/metrics'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8501']
```

But first make sure you can see the metrics exported at http://localhost:8501/monitoring/prometheus/metrics in your browser. Else poke around (with your browser) until you find the proper URL (and reflect that in your config).

Comment: Also, pass the configuration file to your container (`-t --monitoring_config_file=/monitoring_config.txt`) and make sure that path is accessible from within the container.